# Android studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies, google-maps-android-api-2

when i add google map and try to build the project I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

This is my gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.behinlabs.***"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

}

Comment: close Android studio, open projects directory and remove both `build` and `app/build` folders. Open your Android Studio. It should work

Comment: First of all, do not use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'` instead use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'`